# How GAN generator produce integer RGB colored picture?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-networks

For traditional neural networks, I know that we can't constraint the output to be strict integers. My question is what technique does GANs use to produce integer outputs, that can be then converted to RGB colored pictures?

Comment: I think the value is rounded to the nearest integer. Or whatever rounding scheme is preferred.

Comment: @PyWalker27 Thanks, I was thinking perhaps there might be some technique in there.